# finding text from sibling elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamically generated HTML table that I want to use with JQuery. It looks kind of like this, only with more `<tr>` elements.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="name"> Apples </td>
    <td class="value"> 2.33 </td>
    <td class="amount"> <input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The script I'm writing would take whatever's in the text input field, multiply it by the float specified in the value `td` and output it. However, I have problems getting to that `<td>` using JQuery.

I tried something like

```
parseFloat($(".amount input").parent().siblings($("td.value")).text())
```

to get the value, but it doesn't work - it seems to be trying to multiply it by every  element regardless of the class. I tried a `<tr>` where the only data was integers...

`2013-8-28 | 2.1 | 20`

...and it spat out 4026. I have no idea why.

So, the question remains: how do I get the contents of the `<td>` with the class `value` starting from the `input` on the same `<tr>`?

Comment: `$(".amount input").parent().prev()` gets the previous sibling `$(".amount input").parent().siblings('.value')` is another option. then you can add `.text()` to get what's in there

Comment: do you have a change event on the inpur field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about

```
$(".amount").parent().find('.value').text();
```

Comment: `parent()` is the `td.amount`

Comment: And by adding another parent() method on there it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').on('blur', function(){
       alert($(this).val() * $(this).parent().siblings('.value').text()); 
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try

*HTML*

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="val1" class="name"> Apples </td>
    <td id="val2" class="value"> 2.33 </td>
    <td class="amount"> <input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*JavaScript*

```
function getvalue()
{
  var name = (document.getElementById('val1').innerText || document.getElementById('val1').textContent);

  var value = parseFloat(document.getElementById('val2').innerText || document.getElementById('val1').textContent);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$('.amount').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), amount = parseFloat($this.find('input').val()) || 0, rate = parseFloat($this.prev().text()) || 0;
    console.log(amount * rate)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.siblings($("td.value"))
```

to

```
.siblings('td.value')
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v69FR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This should also work

```
$('input').on('blur', function(){
   alert($(this).val() * $(this).parent().siblings('.value').text()); 
});
```

Working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/wMtnf/)

Answer (score 0):

The selector in your `siblings()` function is wrong. Try this:

```
parseFloat($(".amount input").parent().siblings(".value").text())
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bpXXF/)

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
$('input').on('blur', function(){
   var value = $(this).closest("tr").siblings(".value").text(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to do :

```
$(".amount input").parent().prev("td.value").text() //good to use
```

or

```
$(".amount input").parent().siblings("td.value").text()
```

or

```
$(".amount input").parent().parent().find("td.value").text()
```

Full working demo

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qFq5S/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I have done with keyup event you can however you want ,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ACH7c/)

```
    jQuery(function(){
        $('.amount input').keyup(function(){
            var input_value = this.value;
            var values = $(this).parent().prev().text();
            alert(input_value * values);
        })
    })
```